# Website Error Word Press home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/blocks.php on line 20

Tags: php

home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/blocks.php on line 20
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given in /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/blocks.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/blocks.php(20): strpos(Array, 'file:') #1 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/blocks.php(84): remove_block_asset_path_prefix(Array) #2 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/blocks.php(330): register_block_script_handle(Array, 'viewScript') #3 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/blocks/navigation.php(672): register_block_type_from_metadata('/home/yvnglvste...', Array) #4 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): register_block_core_navigation('') #5 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #6 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #7 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-settings.php(598): do_action('init') #8 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-config.php(107): require_once('/home/yvnglvste...') #9 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/yvnglvste...') #10 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/yvnglvste...') #11 /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/index.php(17): require('/home/yvnglvste...') #12 {main} thrown in /home/yvnglvster/yvnglvster.com/wp-includes/blocks.php on line 20

thats the error and i have no idea how to fix it.

I tried deleting .maintenance file and then i got a fatal error.  enabled debug mode on website to see error

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled on this so bit late but for future reference if you have the original installation zip file downloaded from wordpress that matches the version you were running before it crashed then use that otherwise download the latest wordpress installation zip file.

Make a backup copy of your webserver folder and if you are able to then backup the database eg using phpMyAdmin.

Extract the wordpress installation zip file to a temporary location.

Delete the entire `/wp-content` folder and `wp-config-sample.php` file from the temporary location.

Now replace the folders and files of the failing wordpress site with the ones from the temporary location.

Hopefully this will get wordpress running up again. Maybe the error was caused by a wordpress or plugin update like woocommerce that timed out?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I just used a old backup and its now fine. Thanks for your help